# Connecting VLC Plugin

Tags: c#, vlc, rtsp

I want to make stream application for RTSP cam to open VLC
when I press the button show to me the stream in the application but it doesn't show to me anything I want the program to display the stream in VLC

this the code of the application using c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace vlc
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void axVLCPlugin21_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://192.168.0.209:554/mpeg4", "live", "network-caching=75");
        //pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Grats. Most ridiculous formulation I see today. You are NOT "Connecting C# to rtsp" at all - you do nothing with rtsp. YOu hand over a URL to a plugin of a third party. This is like saying "I fly a plane to wherever" when you are a passenger. What about you reformulate the question and tag it properly (I see nothing there that refers to visual studio - otherwise please also tag it with your car brand).

Comment: thank you about your silly comment-_-

Comment: Thanks for your idiotic attitude. Btw., why are you streaming IN visual studio? Why do you stream IN visual Studio wthout a Visual Studio extension?

Comment: Does the same work if you open the stream in VLC Player?